# Will Facebook API v2.0 affect Gigya, Janrain to obtain user's data in API v2.0 for commercial use?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, janrain, gigya

According to [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading/) , existing Facebook apps that using version 1 will expire on April 30th, 2015. Version 2 api require developers to review every extra permissions beside public information that needed for the apps. Is this going to affect Gigya and Janrain? How does Gigya, Janrain going to do this? Are they going to submit review 1 by 1 and wait for approval?
Is Facebook going to approve if it is for commercial uses?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it seems to be Facebook support issue, not a specific programming question.